# Using a bib key containing an ampersand (e.g 2000A&AS..143..391S) in table?

Tags: tables, citing, ampersand

I am currently stuck with this issue.

The following is a typical .bibtex entry of a paper that I need to reference:

```
@ARTICLE{1996A&A...307L..41V,
   author = {{Vink}, J. and {Kaastra}, J.~S. and {Bleeker}, J.~A.~M.},
   title = "{A new mass estimate and puzzling abundances of SNR Cassiopeia A.}",
   journal = {\aap},
   keywords = {ISM: ABUNDANCES, ISM: INDIVIDUAL OBJECTS: CAS A, ISM: SUPERNOVA REMNANTS, X-RAYS: ISM},
   year = 1996,
   month = mar,
   volume = 307,
   pages = {L41-L44},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1996A%26A...307L..41V},
   adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

I use `\citet{1996A&A...307L..41V}` as an entry in a table to reference this. If the bib key (e.g: 1996A&A...307L..41V) does not contain an ampersand, the reference will work perfectly (and will also reference properly if not in a table).  However, if it does contain one and is in the table, I get the error message:

> Argument of \@for has an extra }.

I have tried to put a backslash before the ampersand, though, this just returns the error:

> Missing \endcsname

Also, I'm not sure if such a 'fix' would help, as I need the bibcode to be the same as the one in my .bib file.

I know I `can' take the ampersand out.. However, I am scripting the output straight from importing these bibcodes, so I would very much like to be able to leave the ampersand in the bibcode.

Table:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Integrated values of object}
\centerline{
\begin{tabular}{ccccl}
\hline
Freq & Flux  & $\Delta$Flux  & Reference & Comment \\
\hline
408 &   640.0 & --- & \citet{1983ApJS...51..345M}    & comment1 \\
408 &   600.0 & --- & \citet{1996A&A...307L..41V}    & comment2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

So the first reference will work, however, the second will not.

Hope this clears it up.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why does your bibkey have an ampersand in it? Ampersand has other use in latex, you need to use the escape character (ie \ ) however, I am not sure it will work here.

Comment: Sorry, the original post has been updated to provide more information about the issue.

Comment: Thanks for adding a lot more information. Real quick: Is editing the `.bib` file and, specifically, removing or modifying "special-to-TeX characters" an option for you? In the long run, not having to deal with "special characters" (such as `&`, `#`, etc) in bib keys will save you a lot of hassle. By the way, don't use the PlainTeX `\centerline{...}` method. Try using the command `\centering` (which doesn't take an argument) instead.

Comment: Just filter out the ampersand in your script. I have to say such awful names indicate you're probably taking the wrong path towards the solution or using inappropriate API.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to "verbatimize" the ampersand and replace the tabular ampersand with something equivalent. The command `\amp=&` makes `\amp` a replacemnet for `&` in most usage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\let\amp=&     % now most uses of & can be replaced with \amp
\catcode`\&=12 % now & is nonspecial
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccl}
\hline
Freq\amp Flux \amp $\Delta$Flux  \amp Reference \amp Comment \\
\hline
408 \amp 640.0\amp --- \amp \citet{1983ApJS...51..345M} \amp comment1 \\
408 \amp 600.0\amp --- \amp \citet{1996A&A...307L..41V} \amp comment2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{yourbib}
\end{document}
```

It is also possible to replace the tabular ampersand with a single character: after

```
\catcode`\?=4
```

you can use `?` for the cell separator in `\tabular`. You must be careful to do this locally, or else choose a character not otherwise in use. Note that giving `&` a category of 12 makes it printable. In all font encodings I know of, it prints as an actual ampersand.

Answer (score 2):

Just protect the `\citet` with an additional pair of braces:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccccl}
\hline
Freq & Flux  & $\Delta$Flux  & Reference & Comment \\
\hline
408 &   640.0 & --- & \citet{1983ApJS...51..345M}    & comment1 \\
408 &   600.0 & --- & {\citet{1996A&A...307L..41V}}    & comment2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

In this way TeX will not be confused with the `&` in the argument of `\citet`.

---

Some remarks on your code.

1. Don't use `\centerline{...}` for centering the table, but rather

   ```
   \begin{table}[!htp]
   \centering

   \caption{Integrated values of object}

   \begin{tabular}{ccccl}
   ...
   \end{tabular}

   \end{table}
   ```
2. Using only `[h!]` as placement option is dangerous and could cause a block of the float queue.
3. The authors in the bibliography entry shouldn't be in braces:

   ```
   author = {Vink, J. and Kaastra, J.~S. and Bleeker, J.~A.~M.},
   ```
4. Conversely, braces should be used in the title field to protect non optional capitalization:

   ```
   title = {A new mass estimate and puzzling abundances of {SNR} {Cassiopeia A.}},
   ```

   Adding a pair of braces would do, but will block the bib style from applying its own methods.